# Allow embedded videos while keeping youtube blocked

Tags: firewalls, http, proxy

Our organization has launched a training program for employees. the hosting server(internal), has YouTube videos embedded. we have YouTube blocked, and employees access the internet via proxy.
How can I allow these specific videos while keeping the YouTube blocked.

Our proxy is not capable of picking URLs of video so we cant configure the URL-based access.
We have perimeter firewall and proxy is integrated with domain controller.

Comment: The irony is that its easy for employees to bypass this but difficult for the company to display its own videos on youtube.

Comment: Can you filter based on the HTTP Referrer or not? If so, you can permit requests which have the Referrer set to URIs on your internal server, and otherwise block. Note that the Referrer is relatively easy to spoof, so it won't work for the most tech savvy employees you have.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, not without doing some specialized configuration in the proxy server (which doesn't seem possible here).

The easiest thing to do would be to download the youtube videos (or find the originals), convert to a format which most computers recognize (.avi or .mp4), store locally on your hosting server, and embed in your webpage via `<video>`.

Comment: Downloading video will be the last solution right now. someone suggested me to try reverse proxy to control the traffic back and allow the whole youtube through forward proxy. Is it possible to use any free proxy tool to configure a reverse proxy for this solution. But then again, i am not sure which proxy can allow the URL fetch of video.

Answer (score 0):

Are these your videos or someone elses? If they are your videos, then I would try some form of internal hosting. If they are not, perhaps you can ask for permission from the owner to use them for your internal purposes (unless they are already on some open form of license). It is relatively easy with browser plugins, websites, etc. to extract the specific videos you need. It sounds like you have a web server internally so you can just use some type of JavaScript player to play the videos.

If these are third party training materials that link out to YouTube, I would try to work with the vendor to see if they have any specific solutions to address this.